# plug opts and when

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How to connect a plug with attributes and expression `when` in Phoenix controller?

now it looks like this:

`plug(MyappWeb.Plugs.Auth when action in [:show])`

I have to add:

`mykey: "my_value"`

I tried different syntax variants, but none worked

`plug(MyappWeb.Plugs.Auth, %{mykey: "my_value"} when action in [:show])
plug(MyappWeb.Plugs.Auth when action in [:show], %{mykey: "my_value"})`

Comment: I did it the same way without the round brackets. Try: `plug MyappWeb.Plugs.Auth, %{mykey: "my_value"} when action in [:show]`

Comment: @guitarman, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the round brackets.

In my project I did the same thing to check wether the current logged in user has a special role. So I needed to define such static options.

I have a plug [method](https://github.com/the-guitarman/club_homepage/blob/master/lib/club_homepage/web/commands/auth_by_role.ex) (`def has_role_from_list(conn, options) do`) which receives the conn object and a keyword list in options.

In my [controller](https://github.com/the-guitarman/club_homepage/blob/master/lib/club_homepage/web/controllers/competition_controller.ex) I call the plug method and I provide the accepted roles as a keyword list:
`plug :has_role_from_list, [roles: ["match-editor", "team-editor"]]`

If I would have to restrict the plug call to some actions I'm free to define it like so: 
`plug :has_role_from_list, [roles: ["match-editor", "team-editor"]] when action in [:create, :update]`

The point is, that the round brackets of the [plug macro](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Builder.html#plug/2) call in your controller should include the parameters for the macro only. In my example it would look like this: `plug(:has_role_from_list, [roles: ["match-editor", "team-editor"]]) when action in [:create, :update]`